# Sending items in a datagrid on form 1 to another datagrid on form 2

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two datagridview's DGV1 which is in form 1 and on form 1 I also have a "Next" button when that button is clicked I want the collection of items in DGV1 to be automatically transferred over to DGV2 which is in Form2. 
Any help would be great
Thanks

Comment: Any code you would like to share? What have you tried?

Comment: What is currently populating your DGVs?  Are they bound to datatables?

Comment: Just use the same datasource...which begs the question why you need a second form.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Plutonix' suggestion, you want to do something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub btn_Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Next.Click
    If DGV1.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then    
        Me.Hide()
        Dim frmForm2 As New Form2
        Dim dgv2 As DataGridView
        dgv2 = frmForm2.Controls("DGV2")  
        dgv2.DataSource = DGV1.DataSource
        frmForm2.Show()
    End if
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if Form2 has basically only a `DataGridView` on it, you could just re-use your whole existing `DataGridView`.  Or just plop the one from Form1 into Form2 (delete the one in the Designer but copy its properties into code below):

```
Private Sub btn_Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Next.Click
    If DGV1.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim f As New Form
        f.Size = New Size(400, 300)
        Dim dgv As DataGridView = DGV1
        dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        ' ... plus any other customized properties
        f.Controls.Add(dgv)
        f.Text = "Form2"
        f.Show()
        f.Activate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:  I've now tested that the first block of code works fine without changing any public/private settings.

Comment: I have got two forms because, in form1, user can select items which need to ordered and these are stored in DGV1 now when the "Next" button is clicked this takes the user to Form2 where they can select suppliers, enter the quantity for each item and print the form. I have tried running the first code, however on line, 5 I get an error of data source' is not a member of 'system.windows.forms.controls'.

Comment: @kartikey Please see/try my revised first block of code.